# EditForm and ContentTypes -> can I edit a list item using a different ContentType than what it was created with?

Tags: content-type

I have a custom list that has been linked to 2 content types. So let's say the NewForm.aspx uses content type #1 (the default) to create the list items. Is it be possible to create a custom EditForm.aspx to edit the list item using content type #2?

I used SharePoint designer 2013 to create a custom edit form and linked the edit form to use content type #2. Then when I test the new edit button SharePoint throws an error. So my gut feeling is that you can only edit the list item with the content type that was used creating it. I hope I am wrong..

regards,
Hubert

Answer (score 0):

No Content Type will be same for New and Edit type. When you are creating any item based on a content type, a internal xml is generated which modifies when you edit it. If you associate other content type with Edit item you are not modifying the already existing XML.

If your requirement is something like this ..you should check the below link :

https://blog.splibrarian.com/2011/03/21/using-content-types-to-modify-the-newform-aspx-and-editform-aspx-pages/

Comment: Tx and clear. What I did manage was to display my list item using ContentType #2 (even though it was created with #1).